# Using .htaccess file to remove a particular segment of the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

My url link looked like:

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/index.php/pages/home
```

Then I wrote the .htaccess file using google as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|themes|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now my link looks like:

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/pages/home
```

Now,I want to remove `pages` from this link. Can anyone help me figure this out?

So, my url could look like:

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/home
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to create a custom route in the application/config/routes.php file, which routes the url 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/home' to 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/pages/home'

Custom routing is described [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

The code will look something like:

```
$route['home'] = "pages/home";
```

**EDIT**

Your controller, method, and variable are named "pages", "view", and "home" respectively. Therefore, you should try the following route instead:

```
$route['home'] = "pages/view/home";
```

Also:

** Reserved Routes ** 
From the codeigniter documentation:

There are two reserved routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
```

> This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the URI contains no data, which will be the case when people load your root URL. In the above example, the "welcome" class would be loaded. You are encouraged to always have a default route otherwise a 404 page will appear by default.

Thus, you should not be setting the default controller to "pages/view/home." Rather, you should create an "index" method in the controller that defaults to the "home" view.

**Also**
Don't forget to change the $config['index_page'] from 'index.php' to '' in the config.php file located in application/config/config.php.

Comment: What is the name of the controller and method you are trying to use to display the content for this URL? Is the controller named "pages" and the method called "home"?

Comment: controller is pages, method is view, and the attribute is home

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view/home';
$route['pages/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1'; 
$route['products/(:any)'] = 'new_/view/$1';

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your rule so that the target is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/pages/$1 [L]
```